# Is it possible to set text or background color outside ViewPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In `ViewPagerAdapter.class`I have 2 layout(whereami.xml and mapview.xml), and use LayoutInflater to inflate each view inside `instantiateItem()`, normally i should set everything(TextView,ImageView etc. according to xml) inside `instantiateItem()`. But in my case, i really need to setText or Background color at `onCreate()` of ViewPagerActivity which extend `MapActivity`

So, Are there anyway to set them in `onCreate()`?

P.S. I try to debug program and found that the process won't call `instantiateItem()` until it get out of the `onCreate()` method. So,The View won't create yet, and programe force close every time when i try to setText because View is Null.

**ViewPagerActivity**

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends MapActivity {
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager pager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);


        //LinearLayout bgcolor = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        //bgcolor.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
        //TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        //text1.setText("somevalue");

    }


}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements TitleProvider {
    private final Context context;
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;
    private View view;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    }

    private static String[] titles = new String[] { "Page1", "Map" };

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View pager, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (position == 0) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whereami, null);
            ((ViewPager) pager).addView(view, 0);

        }
        if (position == 1) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_map_activity, null);
            ((ViewPager) pager).addView(view, 0);
            mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);

            mapController = mapView.getController();
            mapController.setZoom(14);
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

**whereami.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what should be in the TextView in `onCreate()` why not pass it through the constructor of the Adapter?

```
new ViewPagerAdapter(this, "TextToPass");
```

With:

```
private String toDisplay;
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String toDisplay) {
    this.toDispay = toDisplay;
}
```

and:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whereami, null);
TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
textView.setText(toDisplay);
```